# ¿Cómo crear una condición para un txt en python?

Tags: python, tkinter, condiciones, txt

verán soy nuevo en programación y estoy haciendo un pequeño código para registrar datos y generar un TXT con estos. Mi problema es cuando un usuario no contesta un cuadro, ya que en el txt se muestra vacío el campo que no llenó. Por Ejemplo:

Si un usuario contesta **"Edad"** y **"Peso"** y no contesta **"Altura"** espero que en el TXT se vea asi:

**Edad: 25**

**Peso: 175**

> y no así:

**Edad: 25**

**Peso: 175**

**Altura:**

No puedo hacer obligatorio el llenado de los cuadros porque esa no es la idea,
Aquí abajo adjunto mi código. Espero haberme explicado bien y gracias !

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title('A. APP')
root.geometry("290x290")
root.config(bg="gold3")

def Datos():
  Entry1_info = Entry1.get()
  Entry2_info = Entry2.get()
  Entry3_info = Entry3.get()
  
  file = open("Datos1.txt", "a") 
  file.write("Edad: "+ Entry1_info)
  file.write("\n")
  file.write("Peso: "+Entry2_info)
  file.write("\n")
  file.write("Altura: "+Entry3_info)
  file.close()
  
Entry1 = StringVar()
Entry2 = StringVar()
Entry3 = StringVar()


Frame1 = Frame(root, bd=2, padx=10, pady=3)

Label(Frame1, text="Edad: ", font=('Times', 14)).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W, pady=10)
Label(Frame1, text="Peso en KG: ", font=('Times', 14)).grid(row=2, column=0,sticky=W, pady=10)
Label(Frame1, text="Altura en CM: ", font=('Times', 14)).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W, pady=10)

Entry11 = Entry(Frame1,textvariable = Entry1, width=5).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W, pady=10)
Entry22 = Entry(Frame1,textvariable = Entry2, width=5).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W, pady=10)
Entry33 = Entry(Frame1,textvariable = Entry3, width=5).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=10)

Boton1 = Button(Frame1, text="Generar TXT", width=10, command= Datos).grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W, pady=10)

Frame1.place(x=20, y=40)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo validando si un entry está vacío mediante su longitud de la siguiente manera:

```
def Datos():
  Entry1_info = Entry1.get()
  Entry2_info = Entry2.get()
  Entry3_info = Entry3.get()

 #validas si los entry están vacíos, si no están vacíos les añades el prefijo deseado
  if len(Entry1_info) > 0:
    Entry1_info = "Edad: "+ Entry1_info;

  if len(Entry2_info) > 0:
    Entry2_info = "Peso: "+ Entry2_info;

  if len(Entry3_info) > 0:
    Entry3_info = "Altura:: "+ Entry3_info;
    
  file = open("Datos1.txt", "a")

  #si los entry no estaban vacíos los escribes en el fichero
  if(len(Entry1_info)>0):
    file.write(Entry1_info)
    file.write("\n")
  if(len(Entry2_info)>0):
    file.write(Entry2_info)
    file.write("\n")
  if(len(Entry3_info)>0):
    file.write(Entry3_info)
    file.write("\n")

  file.close()
```

Comment: Vaya no creí que fuera tan sencillo! Muchas gracias hermano me has ayudado a pasar mi semestre!